# Get rows based on distinct values from one column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the rows by distinct values in `COL2`?

For example, I have the dataframe below:

```
COL1   COL2
a.com  22
b.com  45
c.com  34
e.com  45
f.com  56
g.com  22
h.com  45
```

I want to get the rows based on unique values in `COL2`:

```
COL1  COL2
a.com 22
b.com 45
c.com 34
f.com 56
```

So, how can I get that? I would appreciate it very much if anyone can provide any help.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specifying column `COL2` for check duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('COL2')
#same as
#df = df.drop_duplicates('COL2', keep='first')
print (df)
    COL1  COL2
0  a.com    22
1  b.com    45
2  c.com    34
4  f.com    56
```

You can also keep only last values:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('COL2', keep='last')
print (df)
    COL1  COL2
2  c.com    34
4  f.com    56
5  g.com    22
6  h.com    45
```

Or remove all duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('COL2', keep=False)
print (df)
    COL1  COL2
2  c.com    34
4  f.com    56
```

Comment: apologies! I was away for 2 days

Comment: Faced the same issue, solution wors well, but I needed to sort the data first by the relevant column before dropping the duplicates

Comment: I had to do `df = df.drop_duplicates(['COL2'])`. Note that the`'COL2'` is inside `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` in combination with `first` and `last` methods.
To get the first row from each group:

```
df.groupby('COL2', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   COL2   COL1
0    22  a.com
1    34  c.com
2    45  b.com
3    56  f.com
```

To get the last row from each group:

```
df.groupby('COL2', as_index=False).last()
```

Output:

```
   COL2   COL1
0    22  g.com
1    34  c.com
2    45  h.com
3    56  f.com
```