# Merging two Irregular data frames in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames df1 and df2

```
    ID      Range(US)            Count(US)          Mean(US)
0   690      1-3                 266                4.0
1            4-7                 277                NaN
2   354      1-3                 233                2.0
3            4-7                 85                 NaN
4   947      1-3                 156                4.0
```

and

```
    ID   Range(UK)           Count(UK)          Mean(UK)
0   690      1-3                 186                4.0
1            4-7                 25                 NaN
2   354      1-3                 44                 1.0
3   947      1-3                 213                3.0
4            4-7                 33                 NaN
```

I merged using the code:
`In:df=df1.merge(df2, left_on='deviceid',right_on='deviceid', how='left')
    df`

```
 ID  Range(US)   Count(US)    Mean(US)   Range(UK)  Count(UK)    Mean(UK)       
 0  690    1-3      266         4.0        1-3        186         4.0
 1         4-7      277         NaN        4-7        25          NaN
 2         4-7      277         NaN        4-7        33          NaN
 3  354    1-3      233         2.0        1-3        44          1.0
 4         4-7      85          NaN        4-7        25          NaN
 5         4-7      85          NaN        4-7        33          NaN
 6  947    1-3      156         4.0        1-3        213         3.0
```

From the above we see that the values are repeated again for some values if not present

But the expected output is

```
   ID  Range(US)   Count(US)  Mean(US)   Range(UK)  Count(UK)    Mean(UK)       
 0  690    1-3      266         4.0        1-3        186         4.0
 1         4-7      277         NaN        4-7        25          NaN
 2  354    1-3      233         2.0        1-3        44          1.0
 3         4-7      85          NaN        Nan        NaN         NaN
 4  947    1-3      156         4.0        1-3        213         3.0
 5         4-7      Nan         Nan        4-7        33          Nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove replacing `duplicated` `ID` in both `DataFrames`:

```
#df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].mask(df['ID'].duplicated(), '') 
#df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].mask(df['ID'].duplicated(), '') 

print (df1)
    ID Range(US)  Count(US)  Mean(US)
0  690       1-3        266       4.0
1  690       4-7        277       NaN
2  354       1-3        233       2.0
3  354       4-7         85       NaN
4  947       1-3        156       4.0

print (df2)
    ID Range(UK)  Count(UK)  Mean(UK)
0  690       1-3        186       4.0
1  690       4-7         25       NaN
2  354       1-3         44       1.0
3  947       1-3        213       3.0
4  947       4-7         33       NaN
```

And then merge by both columns with outer join:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID', 'Range(US)'], right_on=['ID', 'Range(UK)'], how='outer')
print (df)
    ID Range(US)  Count(US)  Mean(US) Range(UK)  Count(UK)  Mean(UK)
0  690       1-3      266.0       4.0       1-3      186.0       4.0
1  690       4-7      277.0       NaN       4-7       25.0       NaN
2  354       1-3      233.0       2.0       1-3       44.0       1.0
3  354       4-7       85.0       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
4  947       1-3      156.0       4.0       1-3      213.0       3.0
5  947       NaN        NaN       NaN       4-7       33.0       NaN
```

Comment: df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].mask(df['ID'].duplicated(), '') what is df here?

Comment: @san - it is typo, need `#df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].mask(df1['ID'].duplicated(), '') 
    #df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].mask(df2['ID'].duplicated(), '')`

Comment: still not getting the expected output

Comment: if change `outer` to `left` or `inner` it help?

Comment: Can you explain more? Problem is with real data? Or if use data sample data get different output like me in answer?

Comment: I got a different answer for this sample data

Comment: Is your `df1` and `df2` like in answer? `ID` column is filled by repeating numbers, there are not wihitespces..

Comment: @san - yes, and it is problem. need numeric values.

Comment: how to fill 0 for all nan values?

Comment: Super, , use `df = df.fillna(0)`

Comment: ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Comment: hmmm, there is problem with `Range` columns, because categoricals. Give me some time for solution.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.23.0 is  my pandas version

Comment: I cannot simulate it, but solution should be `df1['Range(US)'] = df1['Range(US)'].cat.add_categories([0])` and `df2['Range(UK)'] = df2['Range(UK)'].cat.add_categories([0])` before `merge`

Comment: cool worked perfectly but can we delete duplicates for the entire data frame?

Comment: hmmm, hard question. It is up to you, what need. But if need remove duplicates [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43694911/2901002) should help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172554/discussion-between-san-and-jezrael).